# Mocking private static method in a final (utility) class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, utility-method

Is there a way to test the following class, mocking the private method `getMessage()` ?

I've tried with jUnit + Mockito + PowerMock but I could not find a way (without modifying source code or doing reflection changes).

Any idea ?

```
public final class One {
    public static String met1() {
        return getMessage();
    }
    private static String getMessage() {
        return "ciao";
    }
    private One() {
        // Empty
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PowerMockito will let you mock all of the static methods of the class, but you need to make sure your `met1` method still calls the real method:

```
@RunWith( PowerMockRunner.class )
@PrepareForTest( One.class )
public class OneTest
{
  @Test
  public void testOne()
  {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic( One.class );
    try
    {
      PowerMockito.when( One.met1() ).thenCallRealMethod();
      Method getMessage = PowerMockito.method( One.class, "getMessage" );
      PowerMockito.when( getMessage.invoke( null ) ).thenReturn( "test" );
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    assertEquals( "test", One.met1() );
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! I missed the thenCallRealMethod() method. Many thanks.